# Get values filtered by jsonb key

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table called `houses` that has a `jsonb` column called `details` . The structure of the `details` jsonb column is:

```
{
  owner_id: TEXT,
  owner_name: TEXT,
  offers: [{ offer_id: TEXT, offer_value_id: TEXT, offer_value_name: TEXT }]
}
```

Notice, that sometimes offers can be completely empty, such as `offers: []`

So, right now I have a query that lets me get all the distinct house owners ordered by `owner_name`. It looks like this:

```
SELECT distinct ("details"->>'owner_id') as "identifier", "details"->>'owner_name' as "name" 
FROM houses 
order by "details"->>'owner_name' asc
```

I want to do something similar, but now I want to get all the different offer values but just for a specific offer_id. Here is some sample data followed but what I would expect:

id, details

```
1, { owner_id: '1', owner_name: 'john', offers: [] }
2, { owner_id: '2', owner_name: 'charles', offers: [ { offer_id: '1', offer_value_id: '1', offer_value_name: 'offer1'}, { offer_id: '2', offer_value_id: '2', offer_value_name: 'offer2'}] }
3, { owner_id: '3', owner_name: 'melissa', offers: [ { offer_id: '2', offer_value_id: '5', offer_value_name: 'a offer 3'} ]
4, { owner_id: '3', owner_name: 'melissa', offers: [ { offer_id: '6', offer_value_id: '8', offer_value_name: 'offer10'} ]
```

So, say I want to get all the different offer value ids and value names when the offer_id is '2'. The result would be:

```
identifier (this would be offer_value_id), name (this would be offer_value_name)
'5', 'a offer 3'
'2', 'offer2'
null, null
```

Notice that there is `null`, `null` because there is at least two rows that don't have any offers where offer_id is `1`, and I want to get that too. Also, notice that the values are ordered by `offer_value_name` NULLs being last.

I've tried the following but is not working:

```
SELECT distinct ("details"->>'offers'->>'offer_value_id') as "identifier", ("details"->>'offers'->>'offer_value_name') as "name" 
    FROM houses 
    WHERE "details"->>'offers'->>'offer_id' = '2'
    order by "details"->>'offers'->>'offer_value_name' asc
```

And I don't think this approach would work, because if the details offers don't have an offer_id, I also want it to select NULL, this would just filter it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "offers"->>'offer_value_id' as "identifier", "offers"->>'offer_value_name' as "name"
FROM houses
LEFT JOIN jsonb_array_elements("details"->'offers') "offers" ON "offers"->>'offer_id' = '1';
ORDER BY "offers"->>'offer_value_name' NULLS LAST
```

You know you want to get all the records regardless of whether that offer with id 1 exists or not, that's why you do a LEFT JOIN.

The other thing to notice here is `jsonb_array_elements` that is helpful because it expands that json to a set of json values. That way you can access `offers` as if it were a top level field.